# Opening a Sentinel-2 image downloaded from esa scihub in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2, esa

How do I open a Sentinel-2 image that I downloaded from ESA's scihub?

I usually use a geotiff product but I can't find one.

[image: Here are the contents of the file:]

Answer (score 3):

Open the metadata file "MTD_MSIL1C.xml" and select which dataset you want, the 10m, 20m or 60m bands.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are inside the GRANULE folder. There are several subfolders and image format is JPEG2000. Everthing is explained here:
[https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/data-formats#:~:text=The%20SAFE%20format%20wraps%20a,of%20information%20(Figure%201)](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/data-formats#:%7E:text=The%20SAFE%20format%20wraps%20a,of%20information%20(Figure%201)).